# How to create an index out of bounds exception?

Tags: string, arraylist, integer, int, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an unusual question. 
How would you go about intentionally creating an IndexOutOfBoundsException in a perfectly functioning, simple ArrayList code?

Thanks!

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: If it throw the exception, is it still perfectly functioning?

Comment: Oh right, sorry. I'm talking about Java right now. The point is to have a fully functioning code, but for it to still have the IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
List list = new ArrayList<>();
list.get(0);
```

Is that what you are after?